# Can't build new widget on pressing button at run time in FormBuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to build a new widget every time a button is pressed.

I am using object of Global key to change the current state of Form as other local keys doesn't provide me the capability to change the state of FormBuilder

```
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();
```

**Problem is** when I try to create object of GlobalKey(_formKey) under listTile widget that I 'm trying to build on runtime, form builderr text fields don't work i.e appear and disappear instantly! But when create _formKey oustside the listTile widget under stateful widget, many other errors appears
i.e setState() called after dispose(), Global key used for multiple widgets etc.
Should I use here local keys i.e value,object or unique key? But they aren't providing me to change the current state of form builder!

Check my code:

```
class _addMenuState extends State<addMenu> {
  var _price = TextEditingController();
  var _itemName = TextEditingController();
  var _desc = TextEditingController();
  File _image;
  String itemImageUrl;
  List<menu> items = [];
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();

  Future getImageFromGallery() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      _image = image;
      print('Image Path $_image');
    });
  }

  Future getImageFromCamera() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {
      _image = image;
      print('Image Path $_image');
    });
  }
  Future uploadItemOfShop(BuildContext context) async {
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    Reference ref = storage.ref().child("${this.widget.rr.name}'s ${_itemName.text} Price ${_price.text}" + DateTime.now().toString());
    if(_image.toString()==''){
      Flushbar(
        title: "Menu Item Image is empty",
        message: "Please Add some Image first",
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        boxShadows: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.red[800], offset: Offset(0.0, 2.0), blurRadius: 3.0,)],
        duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
      )..show(context);

    }else{

      UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(_image);
      uploadTask.then((res) async {
        itemImageUrl = await res.ref.getDownloadURL();
      });
    }




    /*  setState(() {
      print("Logo uploaded");
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text('Your Restaurnat Logo has Uploaded'),
        duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
      ));
    });*/
  }




  Widget Divido() {
    return Divider(
      thickness: 5,
      color: Colors.black45,
      height: 2,
    );
  }

  Widget listTile(int i) {
    final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();


    return SingleChildScrollView(

      child: ListTile(
        title: //Code not needed here for this question as I haven't used key in it
        subtitle: FormBuilder(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              FormBuilderTextField(
                controller: _itemName,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                name: 'item_name',
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Enter Item name'),
                validator: FormBuilderValidators.compose([
                  FormBuilderValidators.required(context),
                ]),
              ),
              FormBuilderTextField(
                controller: _price,
                name: 'price',
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Enter Price'),
                validator: FormBuilderValidators.compose([
                  FormBuilderValidators.required(context),
                ]),
              ),
              FormBuilderTextField(
                maxLength: 150,
                controller: _desc,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                maxLines: null,
                name: 'desc',
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Description',
                ),
                validator: FormBuilderValidators.compose(
                  [
                    FormBuilderValidators.required(context),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text(
                      "Save",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.red,
                    onPressed: () {
                      debugPrint("null");
                      menu item = menu(
                          _itemName.text, _price.text, _desc.text, itemImageUrl);

                      items.add(item);
                setState(() {
                   _count = _count + 1;
                 });
                    },
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text(
                      "Reset",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    onPressed: () {
                      _formKey.currentState.reset();
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Divido()
            ],
          ),
        ),
        selectedTileColor: Colors.red.shade300,
      ),
    );
  }

  int _count = 1;
  bool _showAnotherWidget = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> children = List.generate(_count, (int i) => listTile(i));

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Add Menu for ${this.widget.rr.name} Shop"),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: children
            ),
          ),
        )

    
    );
  }
}
```